# Typeset commands inside an environment like if they were -out- of the environment

Tags: macros, environments

I'm trying to use a custom command `\dialog[]{}{}` inside an environment `verse` and executing it "as if" the command was outside of the environment.

In short, I'd like to make the command to not be influenced by the environment its called in.

Following here a *not so* MWE where I define the new command `\dialog` and the `change margin` environment which is a rough attempt to reset the margins without success.

First I call the `\dialog` command to give an example of its normal output, then I call it inside the verse environment and lastly I break the lyrics in two verse environment to showcase the desired output.

**I'd like to obtain the last output but with the first code syntax**

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{extramarks}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{verse}
%\usepackage{lineno}
%   \renewcommand\linenumberfont{\normalfont\footnotesize\sffamily}

\parindent 0pt
\parskip 0pt
\newlength{\doublespacelength}
\setlength{\doublespacelength}{1.6ex}

\newcommand{\doublespace}{\vspace{\doublespacelength}}

\newenvironment{changemargin}[2]{%
    \begin{list}{}{%
        \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}%
        \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}%
        \setlength{\rightmargin}{#2}%
        \setlength{\listparindent}{\parindent}%
        \setlength{\itemindent}{\parindent}%
        \setlength{\parsep}{\parskip}%
        }%
    \item[]}{\end{list}}

% \dialog[emotions, actions of the character]{Name}{Line}
\newcommand{\dialog}[3][]{%
  \doublespace%
  \needspace{2\baselineskip}%
  \begin{changemargin}{0in}{0in}%
        { \textsc{#2} \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{(\textit{#1})}%
        \par
        }%
    \end{changemargin}%
  \extramarks{}{}%
  \begin{changemargin}{0.3in}{0in} \texttt{#3} \end{changemargin}%
}


\begin{document}
% Example basic output
\dialog[excited]{Peter}{Oh my god a MWE!}

\bigskip

% Undesired output - but this is how I want to write the code
\settowidth{\versewidth}{My custom lenght}
\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
Some good\\
old poetry,\\

\dialog[excited]{Peter}{Oh my god a MWE!}

or maybe a song\\
or a ballata\\
\end{verse}

\bigskip
\bigskip


% Desired output but I had to split the lyrcs in two verse environments which is unwanted.
\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
Some good\\
old poetry,\\
\end{verse}

\dialog[excited]{Peter}{Oh my god a MWE!}

\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
or maybe a song\\
or a ballata\\
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what else this breaks.  I did 3 things:

1. I modified `\verse` and `\endverse` to define a macro `\verseskip`, inside a group,
2. I changed `\parsep` inside of `\changemargin`, and
3. I did a `\leftskip\verseskip` twice in `changemargin`.

p.s.  If I was obsessive compulsive, I would have changed "a MWE" to "an MWE".

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{extramarks}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{verse}
%\usepackage{lineno}
%   \renewcommand\linenumberfont{\normalfont\footnotesize\sffamily}
\newcommand\verseskip{0pt}

%%% I CHANGED VERSE
\let\svverse\verse
\let\svendverse\endverse
\def\verse{\bgroup\def\verseskip{-1.84in}\svverse}
\def\endverse{\svendverse\egroup}
%%%

\parindent 0pt
\parskip 0pt
\newlength{\doublespacelength}
\setlength{\doublespacelength}{1.6ex}

\newcommand{\doublespace}{\vspace{\doublespacelength}}

\newenvironment{changemargin}[2]{%
    \begin{list}{}{%
        \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}%
        \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}%
        \setlength{\rightmargin}{#2}%
        \setlength{\listparindent}{\parindent}%
        \setlength{\itemindent}{\parindent}%
        \setlength{\parsep}{\parskip}%
        \setlength\parsep{-8pt}% I ADDED THIS
        }%
    \item[]\leftskip\verseskip}{\leftskip\verseskip\end{list}}% I ADDED \leftskip 2X

% \dialog[emotions, actions of the character]{Name}{Line}
\newcommand{\dialog}[3][]{%
  \doublespace%
  \needspace{2\baselineskip}%
  \begin{changemargin}{0in}{0in}%
        { \textsc{#2} \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{(\textit{#1})}%
        \par
        }%
    \end{changemargin}%
  \extramarks{}{}%
  \begin{changemargin}{0.3in}{0in} \texttt{#3} \end{changemargin}%
}


\begin{document}
% Example basic output
\dialog[excited]{Peter}{Oh my god a MWE!}

\bigskip

% Undesired output - but this is how I want to write the code
\settowidth{\versewidth}{My custom lenght}
\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
Some good\\
old poetry,\\

\dialog[excited]{Peter}{Oh my god a MWE!}

or maybe a song\\
or a ballata\\
\end{verse}

\bigskip
\bigskip


% Desired output but I had to split the lyrcs in two verse environments which is unwanted.
\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
Some good\\
old poetry,\\
\end{verse}

\dialog[excited]{Peter}{Oh my god a MWE!}

\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
or maybe a song\\
or a ballata\\
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A partial workaround is creating two version of the \dialog command, one for when it is executed inside and one for outside the verse env. I won't mark this as an answer *yet* for two reasons:

- I'm not executing the \dialog command "as if" out of the verse env, I'm actually closing the env, executing the command and reopening the env which is an unelegant operation imho.
- The output of \dialog "inside" the verse env is somehow with the second line indented even if the newcommand \dialog is the same in and out the verse env. I can't tell as of now why the line is indented and needs further inspection.

Here an MWE stripped to the bones:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{verse}

\newcommand{\dialog}[3][]{%
         \textsc{#2} \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{(\textit{#1})}%
         \par%
\texttt{#3}%
}

\def \dout{\dialog[scioccata]{Nena}{La cioccolata fa schifo!}}
\def \din{\end{verse}\dialog[scioccata]{Nena}{La cioccolata fa schifo!}\begin{verse}[\versewidth]}

\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\currentEnv}{%
     \ifthenelse{\equal{\@currenvir}{verse}}{\din}{\dout}%
    }
\makeatother



\begin{document}

\dout

\settowidth{\versewidth}{E’ una storia triste}
\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
    trallalero\\
    \currentEnv
    trallallà
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: 1) The second line is not indented. The first line is indented with a negative value for `\parindent`.  2) Inside the `verse`-environment `\parindent` is negative causing first lines of verses to stick out. `\end{verse}` does not end the paragraph, thus the first line after `\end{verse}`, which comes from `currentEnv`, has that negative indent also: For seeing this, just try: `\begin{verse}[\versewidth]trallallà\end{verse}\dout`. Solution: end the paragraph via `\par` after`\end{verse}`:  `\def\din{\end{verse}\par\dialog[scioccata]{Nena}{La cioccolata fa schifo!}\begin{verse}[\versewidth]}`

Comment: Perhaps something needs to be done for the obscure case of `verse`-environments being nested. `\begin{verse}...\begin{verse}...\currentRnv...\end{verse}...\end{verse}`.